# mysql insert/update/delete using jdbctemplate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a list of items/objects that I need to insert/update to a mysql table. Each item in the list is row in table.
I want to insert if the item does not exist in the table.
I want to update if the item exist in the table.
I want to delete the row in table if it is not in my list.

So I can first delete all relevant rows in table and then insert all items in my list. 
OR 
Select all relevant items first, figure out in java code what needs to be inserted/updated/deleted and execute respective queries.
What is the best way to achieve this. I'm using Spring jdbctemplate for doing this. THanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) load list of all records IDs from DB (`DB IDs list`)

2) from `DB IDs list` filter IDs which are not presented in your `input list`, remove rows with such IDs from DB (`delete from Table WHERE id IN :list`)

3) filter IDs from your `input list` which cannot be found in `DB IDs list` - insert elements with these IDs from `input list` into DB

4) filter `DB IDs` which can be found in your `input list` (two lists intersection by ID value), update rows in DB which have such IDs with values from `input list`

Answer (score -1):

i can help you with some queries, this example is without auto increment.
id is unique key

INSERT

`INSERT INTO users (id, surname) VALUES (?,?)`

UPDATE

`UPDATE users SET surname = ? WHERE id = ?`

INSERT if does not exist:

`INSERT INTO users (id, surname) VALUES (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = id`

Comment: That I already mentioned in the question. What about the scenario where I need to delete if it exist in table but not in my list?

Comment: At moment when you are deleting some item from your list you should delete it from table.